# Playing parts of an audio file in WebAudio

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit, web-audio-api

Instead of loading 9 different audio files with a distinct sound effect, I have compiled my sound effects into one .ogg file and I have the various start and stop times for each effect. However, I don't see any way to handle this in the WebAudio API. I'm sure there is. Anyone know?

Comment: Can you maybe explain a little more thoroughly what you want to accomplish? Are you trying to play all of these sounds at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it.

```
var context = new AudioContext();
var mainNode = context.createGainNode(0);
mainNode.connect(context.destination);

function play_sound(sound, start, length) { 
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = get_buffer(sound); // assume get_buffer gets a file that has already been
    source.connect(mainNode);          // loaded and decoded with context.decodeAudioData()
    source.start(0, start, length);
}

// lets say I want to play a 0.2 second sound effect in sfx.ogg starting at 0.5 seconds.
play_sound('sfx.ogg', 0.5, 0.2);
```